# How to save data in DB using nodejs if data is coming as result in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, database

I am creating nodejs application in which result is coming doing some logic and calculation using JS.I know if we need to save data from HTML we use name variable to make it easy and put data in DB but i want to know on below code how should i create routes to insert data .

HTML file :-

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section1" class="tab-pane fade">
  <div class="section-1-questions">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 1:</legend>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-check section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios1" value="1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input " type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios2" value="2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios3" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">3</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 2:</legend>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-check section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios4" value="1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios4">1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios5" value="2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios5">2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios6" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios6">3</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 3:</legend>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-check section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios7" value="1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios7">1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios8" value="2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios8">2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-1">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios9" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios9">3</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
</div>
<div id="section2" class="tab-pane fade">
  <div class="section-2-question">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios10" value="1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios10">1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios11" value="2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios11">2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios12" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios12">3</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 5:</legend>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios13" value="1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios13">1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios14" value="2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios14">2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios15" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios15">3</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios16" value="1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios16">1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios17" value="2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios17">2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios18" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios18">3</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios19" value="1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios19">1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios20" value="2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios20">2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check section-2">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios21" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios21">3</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
```

JS file:-

```
function displayRadioValue() {
  let section1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-1 > input[type="radio"]')
  let section2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-2 > input[type="radio"]')
  let fullName = document.querySelector('#fullName').value
  let email = document.querySelector('#email').value
  let age = document.querySelector('#age').value
  var ctx = document.querySelector('#resultsChart').getContext('2d');
  let section1Total = 0
  let section2Total = 0
  let section1Question = 0
  let section2Question = 0
  let finalResults = document.querySelector('.final-results')
  let result1 = ''
  let result2 = ''
  finalResults.innerHTML = ''

  //Section 1
  section1.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section2Question++
      section1Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  //Section 2
  section2.forEach(function(radio, index) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      section1Question++
      section2Total += +radio.value
    }
  })

  var options = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Section 1", "Section 2"],
      datasets: [{
          label: 'Total Scored',
          data: [section1Question, section2Question, 30],
          backgroundColor: '#E91E63',
          borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
          label: 'Percentage %',
          data: [((section1Total / (section1Question * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2), ((section2Total / (section2Question * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2), 30],
          backgroundColor: '#004D40',
          borderWidth: 1
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        responsive: true,
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            reverse: false
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }

  //Final Results and validation
  if (fullName.value != '' && email.value != '' && age.value != '') {
    if (section1Total > 0 && section2Total > 0) {
      finalResults.innerHTML += genDetails(fullName, email, age)
      finalResults.innerHTML += "<h2>Results</h2>"
      finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section1Question, section1Total, 1)
      finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section2Question, section2Total, 2)
      finalResults.innerHTML += "<h2>Chart Results</h2>"
      document.getElementById("control").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("resultsChart").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("toemail").href += document.querySelector(".final-results").innerText;
      new Chart(ctx, options); //show chart
    } else {
      finalResults.innerHTML = 'Snap! Please select the atleast one survey question from each section '
    }
  } else {
    finalResults.innerHTML = 'Snap! Please enter your name, emial, age in the first section '
  }
}

function genDetails(name, email, age) {
  var result = "<h2>Personal Info</h2>"
  result += "<b>Full name:</b> <span>" + name + "</span><br>"
  result += "<b>Email name:</b> <span>" + email + "</span><br>"
  result += "<b>Age: </b> <span>" + age + "</span><br>"
  return result
}

function genTable(ques, total, section) {
  var result = "<b>Section " + section + ":</b><br>"
  var tr = "<tr><th>" + total + "</th><th>" + ((total / (ques * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "</th></tr>"
  result += "<table><thead><tr><th>Total Score</th><th>Percentage</th></tr></thead><tbody>" + tr + "</tbody></table>"
  return result
}
$('.btnNext').click(function() {
  $('.nav-tabs .active').closest('li').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});

$('.btnPrevious').click(function() {
  $('.nav-tabs .active').closest('li').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

I want to know what should i add route.js so i can able to save the result of survey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important know the difference between backend and frontend. The frontend is for user interaction and information presentation. And the backend is for data processing and make that the user want to do.

So you should use a Db in the backend. That I can see you are using NodeJS so if you want to store it in a DB you can use a column field type like a string. And when you send this value to the frontend app you can parse it to HTML view.